# Reading JSON file using json.load

Tags: python

I have a simple file (username.json) as shown below:

```
{"lastname": "doe", "firstname": "john"}
```

I use the following code to read the file:

```
with open(filename) as file_obj:
    dictionary = json.load(file_obj)
    print(dictionary['firstname'])
```

But when I print the dictionary value for the key "firstname" it prints nothing.

When I print the dictionary I get the following:

```
{u'lastname': u'doe', u'firstname': u'john'}
```

I know that "u" stands for unicode but for some reason I am not able to use the firstname and lastname keys.

UPDATE:

For some reason it works now!

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by not being able to use the firstname and lastname keys?

Comment: The provided code works just fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.loads` converts a json object to the python equivalent.

This means it uses lists and dicts instead of arrays and objects. You are seeing the representation of the former.

`doctionary["firstname"]` will get you the value in first name (ie, `"doe"`) while it's still a python object.

If you want to see json again, you'll need to pass it through `json.dumps` - but of course you won't be able to manipulate it as above when in that format.

Comment: You should include that in your question then.

Comment: Having an upvoted answer to a question blocks the OP from self-deleting it. Given as they don't seem to actually *have* a reproducible problem, this seems a bit unfortunate.